# mongodb : How to move specific fields from one collection to another collection?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I need to segregate users,allocatedHours,_id field from workname collection to insert that in workedstat collection.

```
db.workname.find().pretty()
{
     "_id":ObjectId("5d9fd8773d598088d2ea5e49")
     "role" : "Developer",
    "status" : "New",
    "title" : "CountySales",
    "desc" : "<p>Countysales</p>",
    "allocatedHours" : 480,
    "priority" : "Medium",
    "reqType" : "New",
    "users" : {
            "assigned" : [
                {
                    "isStatus" : "active",
                    "assignedDate" : ISODate("2020-11-16T12:24:56Z"),
                    "userId" : ObjectId("5d9fd8773d598088d2ea5e49"),
                }
            ],
            "follower" : [
                {
                    "isStatus" : "active",
                    "followerDate" : ISODate("2020-11-16T12:24:56Z"),
                    "userId" : ObjectId("5d9fd8773d598088d2ea5e49"),
                }
            ],
    }
}
```

I need to move that field into workstat collection.I need to do this in aggregate query.
I need to do this for multiple document.

```
 db.workedstat.find().pretty()
    "workId": ObjectId("5d9fd8773d598088d2ea5e49"),
    "allocatedHours" : 480,
    "users" : {
            "assigned" : [
                {
                    "isStatus" : "active",
                    "assignedDate" : ISODate("2020-11-16T12:24:56Z"),
                    "userId" : ObjectId("5d9fd8773d598088d2ea5e49"),
                }
            ],
            "follower" : [
                {
                    "isStatus" : "active",
                    "followerDate" : ISODate("2020-11-16T12:24:56Z"),
                    "userId" : ObjectId("5d9fd8773d598088d2ea5e49"),
                }
            ],
    }
```

Comment: 1) find query, 2) loop result from find query and prepare update query and execute query.

Answer (score 0):

Would be this:

```
db.workname.aggregate([
   { $project: { users: 1, allocatedHours: 1, _id: 1 } },
   { $merge: { into: "workedstat" } }
])
```

Comment: does this $merge support for 4.0 version, even I have a similar situation like this. when I tried this  I m getting this error *"errmsg" : "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$merge'"*

Comment: `$merge` is new in version 4.2

Comment: do u have any other alternative option that supports on 4.0 version?

Comment: No - apart from upgrading a 3 year old release to a newer version. Or you can run an update for each document one-by-one but this may take a lot of time.